# Subgroups of S4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

There is a question in Artin's algebra whereby you are given the canonical homomophism $\varphi : S_4 \rightarrow S_3 $ and asked to find the 6 subgroups of $S_4$ that contain the kernel.

My question is, why are there only 6? Since the kernel is a normal subgroup of $S_4$ why can't I take every subgroup of $S_4$ (say $H$) and create a subgroup $HK$? Will this not contain the kernel?
Thanks.

Comment: The subgroups of $S_4$ containing $\ker \phi$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the subgroups of $S_3$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen ok thanks! do you have any pointers about how I can prove that to myself? I'm still a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might happen that $HK=GK$ for different subgroups $H,G$, and in fact this is the case.